# Sufficient condition for the derived subgroup of a finite matrix group to be irreducible

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $ G $ be a finite subgroup of $ SU(n) $. Suppose that $ G $ is not contained in any positive dimensional subgroup of $ SU(n) $. Then certainly $ G $ is irreducible. Must it also be the case that the derived subgroup $ G'=[G,G] $ is irreducible?

More generally, let $ G $ a finite primitive subgroup of $ SU(n) $. Is $ G' $ always irreducible?

Recall that we say a subgroup $ G $ of $ GL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ is imprimitive if we can write $ \mathbb{C}^n=V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_k $ as a direct sum of smaller subspaces such that every $ g \in G $ just permutes the subspaces. In other words, for any $ g \in G $ the subspaces $ g(V_1) \oplus \dots \oplus g(V_k) $ are just a permutation of $ V_1 \dots V_k $. That is, $ g(V_i)= V_{\sigma(i)} $. If no such decomposition is possible then we say that $ G $ is primitive.

Both claims are true for $ SU(2) $. Both claims also appear to be true for examples I can think of for $ SU(3) $ and $ SU(4) $.

Comment: If $G'$ is not irreducible then the collection of fixed subspaces forms a set of subspaces permuted by $G$, hence $G$ is not primitive.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think you need to consider the case when the action of $G'$ is homogeneous. But in that case by Clifford's Theorem we would have a tensor product of irreducible projective representations of $G'$ and $G/G'$, and  the second of those would have dimension $1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn't the action of $G/G'$ on the set of simple submodules yield a map into $GL_n(\mathbb C)$, where $n$ is the multiplicity of a simple module in the restriction? Then $G/G'$ being abelian gives us a stabilized subspace?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven   Yes that's better way of looking at it! In any case, the answer to the question is yes.